# Selenium python locators are not working

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

I'm getting shut down by selenium python when I try to find elements on a page.  Some of my locators are working and others are not.  For example:

- This works: `sel.get_text("//div[@class='fm-title']")`
- This works: `sel.click("link=Scheme 1")`

But the following all give me ERROR: Element not found

- `sel.click("//a[@href='pmc/articles/instance/2586675/figure/F10/']")`
- `sel.get_attribute("//img[@src-large='/pmc/articles/instance/2586675/bin/nihms61582f10.jpg']@title")`
- `sel.get_attribute("//img[@src-large='/pmc/articles/instance/2586675/bin/nihms61582f10.jpg']/@title")`
- `sel.click("//img[@src-large='/pmc/articles/instance/2586675/bin/nihms61582f10.jpg']")`

on the relevant source snippets:

```
<div class="fm-title">Structural Insights into the Mechanism of the PLP Synthase Holoenzyme from <em>Thermotoga maritima</em> 

<a href="/pmc/articles/instance/2586675/figure/F10/" class="icon-reflink figpopup" target="figure" onclick="return startTarget(this, 'figure', 1024, 800)">
    <div class="small-thumb-canvas">
        <div class="small-thumb-canvas-1">
            <img src="/pmc/articles/instance/2586675/bin/nihms61582f10.gif" class="icon-reflink small-thumb" alt="Scheme 1" title="Scheme 1" src-large="/pmc/articles/instance/2586675/bin/nihms61582f10.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Ultimately what I am trying to do is click a link that I locate by its src-large attribute (or find the element with that src-large attribute, and click its parent element link).

I'm using Selenium Server 2.15.0 and the python bindings v2.0b3 and Firefox 8.0 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page url would help, because if the url is: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2586675/
 - all src and href attributes in your html snippet differ:

```
<a href="/pmc/articles/PMC2586675/figure/F10/" class="icon-reflink figpopup"
 target="figure" onclick="return startTarget(this, 'figure', 1024, 800)"
 canvas-rid="_cid___pmc_articles_PMC2586675_bin_nihms61582f10_jpg_">
  <div class="small-thumb-canvas">
    <div class="small-thumb-canvas-1">
       <img src="/pmc/articles/PMC2586675/bin/nihms61582f10.gif"
        class="icon-reflink small-thumb" alt="Scheme 1" title="Scheme 1"
        src-large="/pmc/articles/PMC2586675/bin/nihms61582f10.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

And if this not the case – there is a chance those elements are added to DOM after `DOMContent` or `Load` event is fired, and you need to wait for them before using.

Comment: The page URL I was using was http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/instance/2586675/ which appears to be the same page as what you found (it loads without redirecting in my browser).  Turns out though that when Selenium opens that page, it redirects to the URL you found, and the slightly different attributes in that source are the key to finding those elements.  It works.  Thanks! :)